# Equal emptying disposing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics, combinatorics, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I'm working on a problem that is similar to the [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

**Problem**

I have several bins. Each bin contains several items with the same weight (e.g. 1, 2, 5, 10 Kg). The number of items in each bin is different. I have to implement an algorithm which calculates the number of items that should be dispense in order to reach a certain weight so that over the course of more operations the bins will be empty approximately at the same time.

**Example**

1. B1 has 50 items with the weight of 1 Kg
2. B2 has 90 items with the weight of 2 Kg
3. B3 has 80 items with the weight of 5 Kg
4. B4 has 50 items with the weight of 10 Kg

The Algorithm should calculate the number of items that should be dispose to reach 45 Kg. The algorithm should return a result similar to: 
10*B1 + 3*B3 + 1*B4 = 45 Kg.

I would like to know if there is any known algorithm that can be used to solve my problem. I already have an algorithm that it calculate all permutation necessary to dispense the items necessary for the expected weight, but I have problems to figure out, which permutation should I choose depending of the availability of the items in each bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your problem into a succession of equal-sized bin packing problem by first considering only the bins which have more items than the smallest bin(s), and repeat that until all bins have the same size.

So, use the known (wikipedia article) bin packing algorithm on the aforementioned reduced sets of bins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the bin packing algorithm it the best solution for my problem. I implemented the best fit bin packing algorithm. First I sort the data descending depending on the available items. I iterate through all items until I have a solution or the items list is empty(no solution found). For the following case the algorithm does not find a valid solution:

- B1 40 items with the weight 100
- B2 30 items with the weight 50
- B3 20 items with the weight 20

For the weight 350 the algorithm does not find any valid result.

Result1 (340) 100 50 20 100 50 20
Result2 (340) 100 50 20 100 50 20
.....